# ¿Cómo voy agregando widgets a otro widget en python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, botón

Necesito ir agregando "botones" a un widget en tkinter, los botones se deben ir creando conforme se van agregando elementos a una lista por ejemplo. Lo que debo hacer es ir agregando sitios cercanos a uno ubicación, entonces, si el resultado de google muestra 7 resultados, cada uno de ellos debe ser agregado como botón y al pulsar sobre él, mostrará otra ventana con los detalles del sitio pero eso es lo menos relevante.
Adjunto imagen para mayor entendimiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y como  pueden ver en ella se consultan lugares cercanos en un radio específico y dependiendo de esos resultados encontrados, se agregan los botones de los resultados.
Responder solamente cómo agregar los botones progresivamente, ya que el resto sé cómo hacerlo. Los botones son los que dicen Universidad Hispanoamericana,CONAPE ,etc.

Answer (score 1):

Agregar botones de forma dinámica es relativamente simple. Basta con usar algún iterable que contenga los datos para cada botón (texto, función a llamar al hacer click, posición, etc). Puede ser desde una lista, tupla, set, etc. Una opción que suele ser más cómoda es usar una lista de diccionarios. Un ejemplo demostrativo sería:

```
botones = [{'pos':(0, 0), 'text': 'Primero', 'command':función1},
           {'pos':(0, 0), 'text': 'Segundo', 'command':función2},
           {'pos':(0, 0), 'text': 'Tercero', 'command':función3}]
```

En tu caso debes construir esta lista en base a los resultados que recibes de Google. Una vez cosntruida basta con iterar sobre ella e ir instanciando los botones.

Para mostrar como podría ser algo funcional te dejo un ejemplo. En este caso tenemos una entrada de texto donde podemos introducir los nombres de los botones que queramos separados por comas. Hecho esto, al pulsar sobre el botón <kbd>Crear botones</kbd> se crean de forma dinámica. Podemos poner otros datos en el entry volver a crear otros botones eliminando todos los que había antes:

```
import tkinter as tk



class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)            

        vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill= tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=False)


        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        vscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self.contenedor = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.contenedor_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0,
                                                       window=self.contenedor,
                                                       anchor=tk.NW)
        self.contenedor.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_contenedor)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_canvas)


    def _configure_contenedor(self, event):
        size = (self.contenedor.winfo_reqwidth(), self.contenedor.winfo_reqheight())
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 {} {}".format(*size))
        if self.contenedor.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
            self.canvas.config(width=self.contenedor.winfo_reqwidth())


    def _configure_canvas(self, event):
        if self.contenedor.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.contenedor_id, width=self.canvas.winfo_width())


class Aplicacion:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.botones = []

        self.frame_conf = tk.Frame(root)
        self.frame_conf.pack()

        label  = tk.Label(self.frame_conf,
                          text = 'Ingrese el nombre de los botones separados por una coma')
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky ='nsew', padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry  = tk.Entry(self.frame_conf)
        self.entry.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky =tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S, padx=10)

        boton = tk.Button(self.frame_conf, text = 'Crear Botones', command = self.crear_botones)
        boton.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 1, pady=10)

        self.lbl_info  = tk.Label(root)
        self.lbl_info.pack(padx=10, anchor = 'w')

        self.frame_botones = ScrolledFrame(root)
        self.frame_botones.pack(fill = 'x')


    def crear_botones(self):
        #Eliminamos los botones anteriores
        for boton in self.botones:
            boton.destroy()
        self.botones = []

        #Leemos los datos de los botones a crear.
        datos = self.entry.get().split(',')

        #Creamos un diccionario con los datos de cada boton
        botones = [{'pos':(n, 0), 'text': datos[n],
                    'command':lambda n=n : print('Soy el botón ' + datos[n])}
                       for n in range(len(datos))]

        #Creamos los botones y los posicionamos
        for boton in botones:
            self.botones.append(tk.Button(self.frame_botones.contenedor, text=boton['text'], command = boton['command']))
            self.botones[-1].grid(column = boton['pos'][1], row = boton['pos'][0], sticky='nsew', pady=2, padx=10)

        self.lbl_info.config(text='Creados {} botones:'.format(len(botones)))



def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Aplicacion(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Se incluye una implementación de un `Frame` que permite scroll. Esto es de utilidad si tu lista de botones (resultados) es muy larga. La implementación de este ScrollFrame es una adaptación de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16198198/7131499) del sitio en Inglés. Es mejorable, pero realiza su cometido sin problemas.

En este ejemplo, cada botón imprime su texto al ser pulsado, en tu caso deberás pasarle a `command` una función que haga lo que quieras cuando cada botón sea pulsado.

**Un ejemplo de funcionamiento:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]